# Many to Many Relationship in SQLite Database - Crashes Application

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm having trouble with a SELECT statement in my SQLite Database. When the part of the app relating to this SELECT statement is ran, the app closes. Below you will find a picture of my Database.

[My SQLite Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neCcH.png)

Each time an expense is recorded the expense of course goes into the "expenses" table but it also goes into the "peoplexpenses" table. The expense when created, is entered multiple times into the "peoplexpenses" table as more than 1 person can be related to an expense (hence why the "peoplexpenses" table is there in the first place to prevent a Many-to-Many relationship). So what I'm trying to get is, the person's name along with all their related expenses added together to give a total for the person. Hope that makes sense.

My failing SQL statement is:

```
"SELECT P.name, sum(E.amount) 
FROM " + TABLE_EXPENSES + " E, " + TABLE_PEOPLE + " P, " + TABLE_PEOPLEXPENSES + "PE 
WHERE PE.pid = P.pid AND PE.eid = E.eid 
GROUP BY P.name"
```

Please find the Create Table statements and new LogCat here: https://pastebin.com/8eP1BBCt

Comment: Please post the logcat

Comment: I will have to google that, please give me a few minutes.

Comment: Just noticed that there should be a space at beginning of string "PE WHERE PE.pid..."

Comment: @JohnJoe I have now added the logcat.

Comment: @Dan Fixed that, still crashing.

Comment: Okay, cool. I'll keep thinking about it. No idea yet.

Comment: I had not put a space as mentioend by Dan between "peoplexpenses and PE". I have updated the pastebin link to include the CREATE TABLE statments and the new LOGCAT after fixing the space.

Comment: There are another problem in your `listView`. You should show us how you create the listView and also where the error pointed to

Comment: Just checked the listView and I was retrieving the wrong ID for the listView object. Seems to be working now without any issues! SQL code retrieving the information I need. I was also wondering how I could retrieve the names of people who are paying what expense? Would the code be much different to what's above?